# Recursivly scan sd card android ndk

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

I'm really new in android ndk and I appreciate any help. How can I create recursive folder scanning in c++ with the checking extension ? I know it's really easy to do in java. In java I use this:

```
public void scan(File root) {
        File[] list = root.listFiles(tracksFilter);
        for (File f : list) {
            String path;
            if (f.isDirectory()) {
                scan(f);
            } else if(path.endWith(".mp3"){
                 doMP3(f);
            } else if(path.endWith(".png"){
                 doPNG(f);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: man 3 readdir, or if you are not on a unix-style development machine, see http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir

Comment: You can also have a look at android's mediascanner sources [MediaScanner.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/media/java/android/media/MediaScanner.java) -> [android_media_MediaScanner.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/media/jni/android_media_MediaScanner.cpp) -> [MediaScanner.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/media/libmedia/MediaScanner.cpp)

Comment: Why don't you just make a JNI call to your Java code from C++ side?

Comment: @user2359247, because i want to improve perfomance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's worth keeping in mind that native code won't always result in performance improvements for a number of reasons. It might be beneficial doing a speed comparison between your Java code and the equivalent native code. The results might surprise you :)

That said, the following C++ code should get you headed in the right direction.

```
...
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
....
static const string curDir = ".";
static const string parDir = "..";
....
void iterateDir(string path)
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *drnt;
    dir = opendir(path.c_str());
    while ((drnt = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        string name(drnt->d_name);
        unsigned char = drnt->d_type;
        if (name != curDir && name != parDir && name.length() >= 4)
        {
            if (type == DT_DIR) {
                string newPath = path + name + "/";
                iterateDir(newPath);
            }
            else if (name.find(".mp3") == (name.length() - 4)) {
                doMP3(path + name);
            }
            else if (name.find(".png") == (name.length() - 4)) {
                doPNG(path + name);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help! Finally i decide use java for directory scanning

Comment: Thank you for your code. I guess "unsigned char = drnt->d_type;" is "unsigned char type = drnt->d_type;"